.gitignore doesn't ignore files I need git to ignore
I am using Visual Studio 2022. In my solution, there are several projects. I want to git ignore files like *.dcu and .~ under all project folders.
I add *.dcu and .~ in the .gitignore file that is under the root folder of my solution.
I also tried **/.dcu and **/.~.
These all failed.
Under the root folder of my solution, I run git rm --cached *.dcu and git rm --cached **/.dcu, and same for .~.
I got error messages: did not match any files.
Thank you for help.

Please may you share the contents of the .gitignore file? Also make sure that the files haven't already been comitted.

I just add **/.dcu and */.~
Rest of file is not changed.
This is the part of .gitignore.
User-specific files
*.rsuser
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
**/.dcu
*/.~
User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

Please explain what "These all failed" mean in exact terms. Can you show us exactly what you observe that tells you that git does not ignore those files?

Note that **/.dcu means "any file in any folder where the exact name of the file is .dcu" (meaning, no name, just an extension). Try just *.dcu instead and see if that works.

Thank you for your help. I set *.dcu, it doesn't work. "These all failed" means the settings did not ignore these files. "**/.dcu" was suggested from AI.
